# Postgres JSONB column select statement that handles array and none array entries

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, where-clause, jsonb

I have a postgres db with an email table that has a jsonb column for storing who emails are sent to. If an email is sent to a single person it is stored like

```
{"name": "bob", "email": "bob@email.com"}
```

I can query for this by doing

```
select * from email where (to->>'address') = 'bob@email.com';
```

If the email was sent to more than one person it is stored like:

```
[{"email": "bob@email.com"}, {"email": "dave@email.com"}]
```

And I can query for this like:

```
select * from email where to @> '[{"email": "bob@email.com"}]';
```

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas for a single query that would return the results of both scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `jsonb_typeof()`:

```
select *
from email
where 
    (jsonb_typeof(to) = 'object' and to->>'address' = 'bob@email.com')
    or (jsonb_typeof(to) = 'array' and to @> '[{"email": "bob@email.com"}]')
```